# Cannot add Timestamps

Tags: java, timestamp, addition

Why is getTime() having an error?  I have tried everything,  but cannot figure out what the problem is.  As far as I know, I have converted the String arrayOpportunity[2] into a date.  (It was originally a String.)  Thanks!

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
df.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

// Calendar timestamp = Calendar.getInstance();
// timestamp.setTime(df.parse(arrayOpportunity2)[0]);

arraySuspects.add(arrayGPS[0]);
// }
// long timediff = coord2.getTimestamp().getTimeInMillis() -
// coord1.getTimestamp().getTimeInMilis();

Date convertedDate = df.parse(arrayOpportunity[2]);

Date duration = df.parse("0000-00-00 00:14:59");
Date lastTime = df.parse(arrayOpportunity[2]);

// SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd");

System.out.println(arrayOpportunity[2]);

//  arrayOpportunity[2].setTime(arrayOpportunity[2].getTime() + duration);
//  lastTime += duration;
arrayOpportunity[2].setTime(arrayOpportunity[2].getTime() + (((14 * 60) + 59)* 1000));
```

Comment: The method getTime() is undefined for the type String

Comment: You probably mean to reference lastTime then.

Comment: THANKS!!!!! it works great now. thanks justin and everyone else!

Comment: why dont you replace `arrayOpportunity[2].getTime()`  with `lastTime.getTime();`. I doubt `arrayOpportunity[]` has Date object.

Comment: @SamuelKnox - if my solution below fixes your problem please mark it as the answer to close out this question, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Calling `df.parse(arrayOpportunity[2]);` does not convert `arrayOpportunity[2]` to a `Date`, it assigns that value to `lastTime`. In your code call `lastTime.getTime()` instead of `arrayOpportunity[2].getTime()` as `arrayOpportunity[2]` is still a `String`

```
// Create your date parser
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat();
// Set the date pattern
df.applyPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
// Create a Date object by parsing the value of arrayOpportunity[2]
Date lastTime = df.parse(arrayOpportunity[2]);
// Set a new value to the Date object by performing a calculation on the result of getTime()
lastTime.setTime(lastTime.getTime() + (((14 * 60) + 59)* 1000));
```